# Consume data from specified shard

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to implement Kinesis consumer in Spring Boot application, the main problematic requirement for me, that I need to consume data from specific shard only(I have a name of it). As I understand with [spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc) it's not possible to do or I'm missing something? Maybe it possible to implement with KCL? [It's look possible to do this with custom client](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/kinesis/src/main/java/com/example/kinesis/KinesisStreamEx.java) Anyway I need to use SubscribeToShard somehow.

Comment: I dont think it is supported at this moment and as per this reported issue they dont have plan to support this. (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/issues/35)

You need to develop custom client to consume from single shard

Comment: Ajinkya, thank you for answer! Looks like the only way is to develop low-level client like here https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/kinesis/src/main/java/com/example/kinesis/KinesisStreamEx.java